# Chai-http/mocha always returns a HTTP 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

This is my test file.

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
const app = require("../app");
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");

let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);
describe("Basic Test", () => {
    it('should always pass', function () {
        expect(true).to.equal(true);
    });
});

describe("Server Connectivity Test ", () => {
  it("welcomes user to the api", done => {
    chai
      .request('http://localhost:3000')
      .get('/')
      .end((err:any, res:any) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.have('success');
        done();
      });
  });

});
```

My basic test passes but my server connectivity test fails with the following error

```
1) Server Connectivity Test
      welcomes user to the api:

      Uncaught AssertionError: expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 404
      + expected - actual

      -404
      +200
```

The app.js is standard app nothing different, a small snippet is below

```
import express = require('express');
import routes from './routes/index';

const app: express.Application = express();
const router = express.Router();
const PORT:number = 3000;
...
//app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.use('/', routes);
...
export default app;
```

I updated my code to add the part where I am doing the router and the server start.

I fixed the / routes as suggested in the comments in the post. Now I seem to load the app modules but the code is failing at the Oracle DB connection which if I do npm start is working

```
TypeError: ConnectionOPDB.init is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\potta\Documents\develop-potta\app.ts:35:16)
```

At line 35 is

```
ConnectionOPDB.init();
```

This is workin if I don't run chai/mocha but just run the app using node app.js

Comment: From your code, you don't have an endpoint for your `/` route...

Comment: I added the code to display the router parts of the code and server start.

Comment: There is no route path `/`.

Comment: Fixed the / route but now seeing the issue that the connection object is not loading which is working when I run the app normally.